# Load page in <object> with link

Tags: html, internet-explorer, object, iframe

I am trying to load a HTML page into a object but it does not work in IE, OK I kan use Iframes but don't want to.

Here some code that does work in IE and FF:

**HTML**

```
<a href="home.html" target="content">home</a>

<iframe name="content" src="about.html"></iframe>
```

Here some code that does NOT work in IE:

**HTML**

```
<a href="home.html" target="content">home</a>

<object type="text/html" data="about.html" name="content"></object>
```

In FF the home.html page is loaded in the object but in IE it opens the home.html in a new window instead of the object.

Hope you guys have an anwser for me.